# Add SHA-1 from production certificate for GCM/FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-signing

I have an app that is using FCM. I've added package to the FCM and it said "Debug signing certificate SHA-1 (optional)", so everything works as expected.

Now I'm preparing it for the release and wonder do I need to change this SHA-1 certificate to value from the release certificate or it's not required and for release I should leave everything as it is?

Comment: yes, you must add SHA-1 of release certificate (not necessarily change debug certificate's SHA-1, you can have both)

Comment: But where I should add it ? I can't find that row in firebase google console.

Comment: since I can attach image in comment, I explain it through "Answer". I hope it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must add SHA-1 of release certificate. you can add SHA-from settings button
[image: Firebase Project Settings]

and then add fingerprint:
[image]

you can have both SHA-1 of debug and release certificate. so the app will work both in debug and release mode.

Answer (score 3):

Do I need to provide a SHA-1 when adding an Android app?

A SHA-1 is only required if you are using either Firebase Invites or Firebase Dynamic Links. Adding a SHA-1 to your project simplifies the Google Sign-In configuration with Firebase Authentication.

If you're not using these features, you don't have to provide a SHA-1.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/

Answer (score 0):

As this was an optional field if you added any value of SHA1 it means it will become that SHA 1 dependent only so as far as you change signing config sha1 will need to change, however you can remain field empty if you want to work it on both.