# how to enable Firebase Cloud Messaging in an apk published in the play store

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-console

I have developed an application using android studio. It is already published in the google play store.

This application uses the Firebase FCM service for push notifications.
During the development stage, this worked perfectly. But since the publication in the play store,  the SendMessageNotification function is not executed in the firebase backend (*Firebase functions*).

I have entered the api key in the console, as shown: 
[image].

However, the service continues without running.

Have I skipped a step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557218/add-sha-1-from-production-certificate-for-gcm-fcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you gone through the [firebase launch checklist](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist)?

Specifically, have you remembered to add the production certificate for your app as well as the development certificate? From the above page "Add a release SHA1 fingerprint for Android apps in the Firebase console (for OAuth client IDs)."

I don't know if this affects client messaging or not.